# How can a Java class in a Jar read a external XML configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, jar, path

I got a common jar that used for creating Database Connection Pool with the datasource XML configuration 'db2.xml', which is under the same path of this JAR, like:

```
Project/
       -- lib
              -- db2.xml
              -- common.jar
```

Following the code for reading the db2.xml:

```
    private BeanFactory() {
            try {
                beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
                xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((BeanDefinitionRegistry)
                   beanFactory);
                resource = new ClassPathResource("db2.xml");
                xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Always error happens:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException 
parsing XML document from class path resource [db2.xml]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db2.xml] cannot be opened 
because it does not exist
```

So it must be caused by 'db2.xml' cannot be found. Whether configuration file are set `resource = new ClassPathResource("/db2.xml")` or `resource = new ClassPathResource("lib/db2.xml")` or `resource = new ClassPathResource("../lib/db2.xml")`; I t all dose not work. How do I set a relative path for this.

```
resource = new ClassPathResource(CONFIGURATION_PATH);
```

This is a Java project. I works when I put the db2.xml into the common jar.

Comment: it does not make sense to add `db2.xml` in `lib` dir, still try `"classpath:lib/db2.xml"`

Comment: What do you mean? Using "classpath:lib/db2.xml" replace 'db2.xml' as configuration path?

Comment: You cannot add single files to the classpath (except jars), you need to add the whole folder (and if you do that, I'd not use "lib", because that would add all the jar files twice).

Comment: @BradyZhu : yes, try using it.

Comment: Nandkumar Tekale: Do you mean that do I use a absolute path as configuration path. 'classpath:lib/db2.xml' = classpath + '/lib/db2.xml'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db2.xml should be in classpath.  tell us how you are running the java application. If you are using ide like eclipse, add the lib directory to classpath(build path). If you are using plain java command , then use following command to have lib directory in classpath.

`java -cp {path to lib directory},{what ever jars you have comma seperated} mainClass`

Also by default java command wont have current directory in classpath.

Comment: We call class by command line, but work of calling this class is responsible by others, so I can do nothing about running the command line.

Comment: then either you need to add this file to jar file. Lib directory is not in classpath , so java wont be able to find it. So you may use  absolute path (check another answer which uses System.getProperty("user.dir") ) try that out.

Comment: I strongly recommend contacting the the others who are responsible and editing the command line command to add a class path entry

Comment: Thanks for you valuable suggestion. The people who is responsible to this is my customer, who must prefer the most simple way to call our class. Anyway, I would directly add XML file into the jar.At least it will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File file =  new File(userDir+"/lib/db2.xml");
```

Comment: Because this jar should work in all kinds of OS platform like XP, Linux, etc. I guess this method that uses absolute path will no work.

Comment: Its working dir, check this link [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) & Did you try ?